# What can I do for this apple tree in utah?

Tags: fruit-trees, apples

What can I do for this tree? It seems to be losing bark and it looks like moss is growing on it. Is it sick?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ufNWtzx8jVPRrE9F_gzgduhhU4bvdNSk/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fwrwJY7mK5zdy0no-PZfBUSzovG7IAKo/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Will, could you please include the pictures right in the question? Thanks!

Comment: With these two pictures, and your non-descriptive question.. all I can say is, pick the Apple it produces and eat

Comment: I updated my question. I am worried the bark is falling of and that the tree is sick

Comment: @Will Does the tree produce fruit? Can you take a few more pictures including one that shows the whole tree? Is this tree just a random apple tree you found in an alleyway somewhere or does it belong to you?

Comment: @Rob It belongs to me and it does produce fruit. I can get a picture of the whole tree in about 7 hours

Comment: @Will How is the fruit? Has the production gone down recently?

Comment: @Rob It tastes good, and just inherited this tree. I think it has been badly neglected as I have had to trim it. It had a lot of apples, probably because it wasn't properly trimmed